# How to return all column names/titles (and avoid "TypeError: table.columns(...).names is not a function")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325786/table-columns-is-not-a-function-in-datatable-js).

I create a datatable, then the user can use the search function, click a button and the selected data will then be sent to another function where it is further processed. Initializing the table works fine, also sending the selected data [works as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169649/how-to-get-filtered-data-result-set-from-jquery-datatable). However, I fail to access the column names correctly.

That's the datatables version I use:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

A bit of background: 
By clicking on a link (`#calculate`), a table is created and the column headers look fine, e.g. like this:

[image]

The user can then select entries (here `88`), and the filtered data are then sent back using a second link (`#send_data`). The data used to initialize the column headers look like this (taken from `console.log(data.columns);`):

```
[…]
0: Object { name: "C1", title: "C1", sName: "C1", … }
1: Object { name: "C2", title: "C2", sName: "C2", … }
length: 2
__proto__: Array []
```

and I can also access `table.columns()`, however, when I try `table.columns().names()` or `table.columns().title()` I receive

> TypeError: table.columns(...).names is not a function.

How can I access and pass the displayed column headers i.e. what goes to `col_names` in the code below?

The relevant code looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = null;
    $('#calculate').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON('/_get_table', {
        a: $('#a').val(),
        b: $('#b').val()
      }, function(data) {
      console.log(data.columns);
        $("#elements").text(data.number_elements);
        if (table !== null) {
          table.destroy();
          table = null;
          $("#a_nice_table").empty();
        }
        table = $("#a_nice_table").DataTable({
          data: data.my_table,
          columns: data.columns
        });
      });
      return false;
    });
    $('#send_data').bind('click', function() {
        //console.log(table.columns());
        //console.log(table.columns().title());
        //console.log(table.columns().names());
      $.getJSON('/_selected_data', {

        sel_data: JSON.stringify(table.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).data().toArray()),
        col_names: //what goes here?

      }, function(data) {
        alert('This worked')
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using [this jQuery plugin](https://datatables.net/)? If so take a look at [this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().header()).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: That works with `console.log`, thanks. It then contains e.g. `aria-label="C1: activate to sort column descending"`. Any idea how I now extract all those `aria-label` entries for each column? Or would I have to send it then using e.g. `table.columns().header().html()` and then parse it myself?

Comment: Yep, you could parse yourself - this would give you an array of the header texts:
`table.columns().header().map(function(h) {return h.innerHTML})`

Comment: Try this: `$(table.columns().header()).find('th').map(function(idx, e) { return $(e).attr('aria-label'); })`

Comment: @colin0117: Thanks, the following seems to work: `col_names: JSON.stringify(table.columns().header().map(function(h) {return h.innerHTML}).toArray())`. Feel free to add this as an answer.

Comment: Seems like @colin0117 beat me to it. I had something similar: `table.columns().header().toArray().map(x => x.innerText)`

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr: That also works fine; please also add it as an answer..

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: I tried `col_names: JSON.stringify($(table.columns().header()).find('th').map(function(idx, e) { return $(e).attr('aria-label'); }).toArray())` but this does not return anything; will play with it...

Comment: It doesn't matter - you may have to fiddle a bit with the code to get it to work, but it does (more or less) the same thing as what the others proposed - you can go with one of the other two answers as both are shorter, unless you specifically need to get an array of values of a specific attribute in the header.

Comment: @Cleb: Got a chance to take a closer look at your code; I think you can just store the columns in the table object when you create it, and retrieve them later; pretty straightforward - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
table.columns().header().toArray().map(x => x.innerText)
```

I used the API docs from [DataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().header()). Replacing `innerText` with `innerHTML` also works.

Comment: Cheers, works great. Still feels strange though that there does not seems to be a more straightforward way of doing this...

Comment: @Cleb I agree. There was nothing in the API docs about getting the header titles directly. :\

Answer (score 2):

Extracting the table headers from the HTML table seems kind of hackish; based on your code, I think you can do something like this instead; at the part where you initialize the table variable just add one more line to retain the column list from the JSON data you obtained:

```
table = $("#a_nice_table").DataTable({
            data: data.my_table,
            columns: data.columns
        });

table.columns = data.columns;  // dynamically add a property, store columns
```

Then you should be able to just do:

```
col_names: JSON.stringify(table.columns)
```

Or some variant of that, depending on exactly what kind of data structure is contained in `data.columns` (if it's a simple array, it should work fine).

Comment: Yes, it indeed feels a bit hacky. This approach kind of works, too, but one should not use `table.columns` but e.g. `table.column_names` as `columns` is a reserved word. Problem then is that I always get a dictionary of the type `0: Object { title: "C1", sTitle: "C1" }
1: Object { title: "C2", sTitle: "C2" }` from which I would have to filter the `title` part. And then I am not sure whether the order of the columns is preserved (could use an orderedDict though). I upvoted it as this might work, but I need a few more tests...

Answer (score 0):

I had to get an array of all column names using the DataTables `.settings()` method.

I ended up doing the following:

```
// Initialise your table and set up column names.
const yourTable = $('#yourTableID').DataTable({
   columns: [
        {name: 'FirstName'},
        {name: 'LastName'},
   ]
});

// Get your table's settings
const settings = yourTable.settings();

// Map through the settings.aoColumns object and return each column.name
const columnNames = settings.aoColumns.map((column) => {
    return column.name;
});

console.log(columnNames) // prints: ['FirstName', 'LastName']
```